# Arabic text is not showing in TextSymbol

Tags: android, fonts, arcgis, arabic-support, arcgis-android-api

I need to set Arabic text in `TextSymbol` in android. Here is my code

```
TextSymbol txtSymbol = new TextSymbol(24, "مرحبا", Color.BLUE);
Point pt = new Point(-293826, 7574114);
Graphic gr = new Graphic(pt, txtSymbol);
GraphicsLayer gl = new GraphicsLayer();
mMapView.addLayer(gl);
gl.addGraphic(gr);
```

Note: there is method `setFontFamily()`, I tried with some font, but not working. The is issue is for right to left direction language, like Arabic, Hebrew etc..

Comment: convert it into UTF-8 and then try

Comment: Not Working. Note, The is issue is for right to left direction language, like Arabic, Hebrew etc.

Comment: i tried my self it working

Comment: Hi Ganesh , would you please share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way convert Arabic text into UTF-8

```
   String input = "مرحبا";
   String arabicString= new String (input.getBytes("UTF8")); 

    TextSymbol txtSymbol = new TextSymbol(24, arabicString, Color.BLUE);
    Point pt = new Point(-293826, 7574114);
    Graphic gr = new Graphic(pt, txtSymbol);
    GraphicsLayer gl = new GraphicsLayer();
    mMapView.addLayer(gl);
    gl.addGraphic(gr);
```

Comment: Not Working. Note, The is issue is for right to left direction language, like Arabic, Hebrew etc..